# Replace EKF by Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks, neural-computing

I made a SLAM (Simultaneous Localization And Mapping) using Extended Kalman Filter (EKF) and it works really good, but I want to see if it works better using Neural Networks.

For the EKF I used an initialization step, prediction step and update step,how can I change that to Neural Networks?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure this can work in the way your question implies. You could certainly use a Neural Network as a parametric model for estimating state transitions and whatnot within an EKF framework, but a Neural Network on its own wouldn't act as a Bayesian estimator like a Kalman Filter variant does.

Comment: And how can I do that? I have no idea and I would like to know

Comment: @choward can you please help me?

Comment: you can use the EKF/UKF as a nonlinear parameter estimation tool where the weights of the Neural Network are what you are estimating. If you look into nonlinear parameter estimation using EKF/UKF, you should be able to find some references. Here's one reference I have used in the past: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/940586/